# Accessing NSManagedObject with ObjectID in NSOperation cause Multithreading violation

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm trying to get an object using MagicalRecord in an NSOperation subclass. I'm well aware that NSManagedObject shall not be passed between thread, so I'm just getting it from his NSManagedObjectID.

This is perfectly working but when I enable "com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1" I get a magnificently named exception :

> CoreData+[NSManagedObjectContext__Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__]:

Here is the code I use for the operation :

```
@interface UserOperation : NSOperation
- (instancetype)initWithUserObjectId:(NSManagedObjectID*) u;
@end
```

And the implementation :

```
@interface UserOperation()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectID * userId;

@end

@implementation UserOperation

- (instancetype)initWithUserObjectId:(NSManagedObjectID*) u{

    if (self = [super init]) {
        _userId = u;
    }

    return self;

}

- (void)main{

    if(_userId){

        NSManagedObjectContext * privateContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];

        // Exception happen here :
        User * currentUser = (User *)[privateContext objectWithID:_userId];

        // ... 
    }
}
```

I did check that the thread of the context and the operation are the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try wrapping the line that generates the exception in `[privateContext performBlock:^{}];`  [See this doc](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/develop/Docs/Threads.md)

Comment: Yes, putting it in the block work, and xCode did not complain anymore. But I checked that the thread used in the block and the thread of the operation are the same. (As it should be since I create the context in the operation). So I was wondering why do I have a violation exception. Is it the debugger who is too picky or what I do might go wrong at some point ?

Comment: The "thread" check in the exception may be checking which queue things are using.   In general you always have to use performBlock with privateQueue MOCs, perhaps because the queue is literally private.

Comment: This seems to be new as of iOS 8.3. In 8.2 and earlier it does not raise an exception.